# How to adapt this iPhone paging control to images instead of colors

Tags: iphone

```
+ (UIColor *)pageControlColorWithIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    if (__pageControlColorList == nil) {
        __pageControlColorList = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIColor grayColor], [UIColor greenColor], [UIColor magentaColor],
                                  [UIColor blueColor], [UIColor orangeColor], [UIColor brownColor], [UIColor redColor], nil];
    }
    return [__pageControlColorList objectAtIndex:index % [__pageControlColorList count]];
}
```

in this above code,i want to repalce the colors display in each page by changing it to uiimages,,i want to load images insted of colors ,,what can i do to solve this problem,,please help

thankzz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use as below for images

```
+ (UIImage *)pageControlColorWithIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    if (__pageControlColorList == nil) {
        __pageControlColorList = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageforPage1.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageforPage2.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageforPage3.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageforPage4.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageforPage5.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageforPage6.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageforPage7.png"], nil];
    }
     //Check whether the **index** supply by you fall within the limit of Image array.
    if(index <  [__pageControlColorList count])
    {
       return [__pageControlColorList objectAtIndex:index % [__pageControlColorList count]];
    }
    else 
    {
       //If the **index** doesn't fall within the limit the Image array then return a default image
       return [UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultImageforPages.png"];
    }
}
```

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad {
    pageNumberLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Page %d", pageNumber + 1];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [MyViewController pageControlColorWithIndex:pageNumber];
}
 error comes in backgroundcolor..

Comment: @nithin :OK, i know, you are not getting background as per your choice Correct ? I will modify the code above ....

Comment: this works for meee..thnkzz jhaliya..i have another doubt ,,if u dont mind plese help me..i want to crop a caricature image by fixing his uppercloth lowercloth and shoes..i want to select any of the above section and tap,touching above selection need to fit the caricature body ,, any solution for this issues?

Comment: @nithin: glad to know it help you...Accept my answer ... will advice you to start new thread (new stackOverflow post).